# Convert Object to a urlencoded String

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a class

```
class Example
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    public String Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

How can I *automagically* convert this object to a urlencoded string and then append it to my hostname?

Urlencoded string:
`prop1=val1&prop2=val2&prop3=val3`

Final result:
`http://example.com?prop1=val1&prop2=val2&prop3=val3`

Comment: I think downvotes mean "you should write your scenerio". Why you want to do this. Where you want to use this? Title is "object to url", tag is "asp.net-mvc", in MVC the best way is the @Darin suggestion. Because UrlHelper is designed to do this.So your question not clear enough. I hope you understand...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an [`UrlHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
var model = new MyClass
{
    Prop1 = 1,
    Prop2 = 2,
    Prop3 = "prop 3"
};
string url = Url.Action("index", "home", model);
// will generate /?Prop1=1&Prop2=2&Prop3=prop%203
```

And if you want an absolute url just use the [`proper overload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505232%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
string url = Url.Action("index", "home", model, "http");
```

Comment: This will work only on MVC, right?

Comment: Of course that it will work, why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asp.Net MVC, then just change the FormMethod to GET.
else, if you want to in code you can use reflection. (as follows)

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Test()
    {
        TestModel model=new TestModel(){Name="Manas",Id=1};
        Type t = model.GetType();
        NameValueCollection nvc=new NameValueCollection();
        foreach (var p in t.GetProperties())
        {
            var name = p.Name;
            var value=p.GetValue(model,null).ToString();
            nvc.Add(name, value);
        }

       var result= ConstructQueryString(nvc);
       return result;
    }
    public string ConstructQueryString(NameValueCollection Params)
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        foreach (string name in Params)
            items.Add(String.Concat(name, "=", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Params[name])));
        return string.Join("&", items.ToArray());
    }
}
```